# Why can we view $N$ as an $S^{-1}R$-module but also as an $R$ module, where $S$ is a multiplicative set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S\subset R$ a multiplicative set. Then one can define the localization $S^{-1}R$ which is also a ring. Now let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be an $S^{-1}R$ module. Then our prof said that we can view $N$ also as an $R$-module.

I don't see why this is true because $S^{-1}R$ is not necessarily a subring of $R$. Does it mean that we can identify $R$ with $\{1\}^{-1}R$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a homomorphism of rings $\rho: R_1\rightarrow R_2$, then any $R_2$-module $M$ can be viewed as a $R_1$-module through the action $ a\cdot x :=\rho(a) \cdot x$ for $a\in R_1, x\in M$. In this particular case, we do have a canonical morphism $R\rightarrow S^{-1}R$, hence any $S^{-1}R$-module is naturally a $R$-module.

When $\rho$ is injective, we can view $R_1$ as a subring of $R_2$. Surely a subring $R_1$ naturally acts on $R_2$-modules, but this is just a special case of the above fact.

Comment: I see the general case but how do we deal with the fact that $M$ is an abelian group  of $R_1$? is this always given

Comment: I don't understand "$M$ is an abelian group of $R_1$"? $M$ is an abelian group which has nothing to do with $R_1$ or $R_2$ actions.

Comment: And for our specific case do you mean the morphism $r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$?

Comment: So I mean an $R$ module $M$ is an abelian group with the action. right?

Comment: Yes, $r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$ is the well-known morphism, which is not necessarily injective. $M$ as a $R_2$-module has an abelian groups structure and a $R_2$-action. To view it as a $R_1$-module, the abelian groups structure is unchanged, and the $R_1$-action is redefined as in the answer.

Comment: Perfect I see it now sorry for the confusion!